# useful hardware diagnostics to run

Tags: hardware

I am wondering what would be some useful hardware diagnostics to run on a new machine (I got a refurbished Lenovo T420).
So far I have done the following

- used `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda1 | grep -i -E 'hours|cycle|count'` to check that my hard disk is not unreasonably old
- used `memtester` to test the memory (but can't use it to test the entire 8 gigs of RAM as the system becomes very unresponsive)
- checked for burnt pixels using videos that are available on youtube
- looked into the `dmesg` and `/var/log/kern.log`. I basically grepped for 'error', 'critical', 'alert' etc. but it's hard to decipher the output and I am not sure I am using the correct grep strings. Some errors were found (reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/848636/89663)) but the output is rather verbose and I am not sure I need to worry about them.

Am I missing / misunderstanding anything on the above and what might be some other Linux tools one might use to ascertain whether the hardware of a machine is in good shape?

Answer (score 0):

For the memory test, rather than relying on the `memtester` application I created a live Ubuntu USB flash drive using [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and run a thorough memory test as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/848772/89663).